# Reduce php if statements

Tags: php

Is there a way to reduce this if statements? I got a bit in trouble, because the var ($c1g, $c2g aso.) also changes in every if statement.

```
        $c1 = $_POST['category_1'];
        if($c1=='perfect')
        {
            $c1g = $perfect[1];
        }
        else if($c1=='good')
        {
            $c1g = $good[1];
        }
        else {
            $c1g = $bad[1];
        }
        $c2 = $_POST['category_2'];
        if($c2=='perfect')
        {
            $c2g = $perfect[1];
        }
        else if($c2=='good')
        {
            $c2g = $good[1];
        }
        else {
            $c2g = $bad[1];
        }
        ...
```

Comment: use case statements

Comment: You're duplicating code, so you can always turn that into a function

Comment: you could also replace `$c1` and `$c2` by an array `$c = [];` and then loop from 1 to 2 or n, so that you have the same switch statement used once (as the code is identical).

Comment: Ah, ok, you guys are right - I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still kind of smells, but if you had an array indexed on the `perfect`, `good`, `bad`:

```
$values = ['perfect' => [1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3],
           'good'    => [1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3],
           'bad'     => [1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>3]];
```

Then you could use the posted value:

```
$c1 = $_POST['category_1'];
$c1g = $values[$c1][1] ?? $values['bad'][1];

$c2 = $_POST['category_2'];
$c2g = $values[$c2][1] ?? $values['bad'][1];
```

And if your posted values were grouped in another dimension like `$_POST['cats']['category_2']` then you could just loop over `$_POST['cats']`.

Comment: I got an syntax error at this, for this "??".

Comment: Wow PHP 5?  Then you would need to do something like `$c1g = isset($values[$c1][1]) ? $values[$c1][1] : $values['bad'][1];`

Comment: Nope, php 7.2 - but the syntax error was only shown as info in my php editor - your updated version cause no error info.

Comment: Dont know about the IDE but it is fine https://3v4l.org/7YgJr